# Bitpay unused address - has balance

Tags: address, lost-bitcoins, bitpay

So, I have a wallet - and the balance is incorrect.

I have looked into it a bunch and finally tracked down what I think is the issue.

If I view all of the addresses used in my wallet I see a list of Addresses with balance and unused addresses.

The problem is that one of the "unused addresses" actually has a balance.

The address is: 1HYMfJhgiprZ3n1oHKiSZ1n2e85Cyn7HAe

How can I make bitpay "use" this address again?

I have tried the following:
  - Clear wallet cache 
  - Scan addresses for fund
  - Restoring wallet to another device

I thought I could try importing that address into electrum - but I cannot figure out how to get the private key for that address out of bitpay wallet.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Bitpay/Copay use Hierarchical Deterministic wallets so you can find all the adresses that has been generated from your root private key (seed recovery phrase)

Here is a guide with more information: https://github.com/OmniLayer/omniwallet/wiki/Finding-and-Exporting-your-private-key-from-Bitpay-Copay